# Does the CK2 AI favour other AI players?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

So, I lost my war in CK2 and my kingdoms of Wales and Ireland are now ruled by Britannia.

The new Emperor instituted max crown authority, destroyed titles, imprisoned several people and generally started racking up tyranny penalties. Naturally I was fine with this. His newly conquered subjects would rebel against me if I mildly annoyed them so I decided to just wait for the rebellion.

They then proceeded to make a few ineffectual factions which did nothing and generally ignore the situation. Since, as I said, I've had rebellions happen to me for far less, I was mildly annoyed by this- especially since Absolute Crown Authority currently makes it impossible to play.

Am I missing something or does the CK2 AI have an irrational tolerance towards other AI players' actions?

Comment: What is your difficulty level? AI gets certain documented bonuses above normal difficulty, some of which may be vassal opinion modifiers (don't remember if that's the case).

Comment: Also, just swear allegiance to the emperor and join one of the factions :).

Comment: When you say "rebel against me" - do you mean rebel with you against the Emperor? Have you tried creating dissent and disturbing the political scene? - Sometimes you need to turn up the heat to cause a reaction...